# Smarty $smarty.post it's not working even all reserved variable it's working include .get etc

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

How I can use this

```
<input name="name" type="input" value="<?php echo @$_POST['name'] ?>" />
```

In smarty engine.

I have try reserved variable

```
{$smarty.post.name}
```

But it's giving error `undefined variable` and my smarty class object name is `$Smarty`.

**Here is my form**

```
<form method="post">
  {if strpos($SessionMessage, "Success") === FALSE}
    <h4 style="margin-top:10px">Post Your Comment:</h4>
    {$Message}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{if isset($smarty.post.name)}{$smarty.post.name}{/if}" placeholder="ext: Jon doe" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Comment:</label>
      <textarea cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control" name="comment" value="{if isset($smarty.post.comment)}{$smarty.post.comment}{/if}" placeholder="comments"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </div>
  {else}
    {$Message}
  {/if}
</form>
```

**This is my PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $Body = trim($_POST['comment']);

    if(!empty($Body)) {
        $Comment = Comment::Make($Photo->id,$Name,$Body);
        if (is_object($Comment)) {
            if($Comment->Create()) {
                $Comment->SendNotification();
                $Session->MSG("Success: Comment is submit, awaiting for approval");
                RedirectTo("photo.php?id={$Photo->id}");
            } else {
                $Session->MSG("Danger: Something is Wrong");
                RedirectTo("photo.php?id={$Photo->id}");
            }
        } else {
            $Session->MSG("Danger: Something is Wrong");
            RedirectTo("photo.php?id={$Photo->id}");
        }           
    }else{
        $Session->MSG("Danger: Comment is empty");
        RedirectTo("photo.php?id={$Photo->id}");
    }
}
```

This is my all code related form you can check this out if i'm doing something wrong in it so kindly let me know. actually smarty .get it's working fine but .post it's not working.

Comment: What does `{$smarty.post|var_dump}` output ?

Comment: `array (size=0)
  empty` this is output

Comment: Then that means that either your reserved smarty variable is not called `$smarty` ([which is strange](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl)) or that your form hasn't been submitted.

Comment: yeah i know so that is why i'm asking why it's not working

Comment: this is reserved variable by smarty i don't need to define it but it's still not working

Comment: Get it's but post it's not working

Comment: What do you mean ? Is GET working ? You could test it by appending `?test=abc` to your URI and add `{$smarty.get.test|var_dump}` in your code. If that works, it means that the problem doesn't come from smarty but that your form isn't sent, which is an entirely other problem.

Comment: Yes it's returning the value of `test` now i have updated my question with form and code you can check this out.

Comment: I added an answer, please check it. Seems to me that the problem is coming from your redirections, which don't send the `POST` data along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding your form and your PHP code, the problem seems obvious : you're adding a redirect, which doesn't transmit `POST` data.

You should send directly your form to `photo.php?id={$Photo->id}` and treat it there, without any redirect.

Answer (score 1):

The variable {$smarty.post.name} should work, but you have to add an isset function.

```
value="{if isset($smarty.post.name)}{$smarty.post.name}{/if}"
```

Comment: it's empty. This is not getting $_POST['name']. I var_dump it `{$smarty.post|var_dump}` this is return `empty` `array (size=0)
  empty`

Comment: You are sure that $_POST['name'] is not null, and you are not overriding the $smarty variable?

Comment: i have updated my answer with my code kindly check this

Comment: You are using method="GET" on your form element not POST. @MuhammadHamzaNisar

Comment: @DevNiels No he's not : `<form method="post">`